# Trouble installing mxnet on OSX Capitan

Tags: c++, unix, deep-learning, mxnet

I am trying to compile `mxnet` (http://mxnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) on OSX Capitan from `https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet`. After following the installation instructions and verifying that all dependencies are in place I am encountering the following error during the build step:

```
In file included from src/c_api/./c_api_error.h:9:0,
             from src/c_api/c_api_error.cc:6:
./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/base.h:104:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/types.h>
```

Tracking down the offending script, `../mxnet/dmlc-core/include/dmlc/base.h`, I locate what see to be the offending lines:

```
extern "C" {
#include <sys/types.h>
}
```

I try out the following patch:

```
extern "C" {
#include </usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/parallel/types.h>
}
```

which produces the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/parallel/types.h:35:0,
             from ./dmlc-core/include/dmlc/base.h:105,
             from src/c_api/c_predict_api.cc:6:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/cstdlib:72:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

Any thoughts? `types.h` definitely exists on my machine, but the script as I get it from the repo isn't finding that file which is killing the build.

Comment: Please don't sign your questions.

Comment: `<sys/types.h>` is not the same file as `<types.h>`. I don't know enough about a mac to say what you need to install [or otherwise do] to fix this.

Comment: Marked as dupe - it's a matter of setting sysinclude to match your machine's install of XCode.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I wasn't sure what to search for or if other software installs had had the same issue.